# Pgpool slave node limit

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pgpool, load-balancing

I've started a new database architecture using pgpool-II 3.4.5, I have 3 servers by now, 1 master and 2 slaves. They are configured to use Master/Slave conf and LoadBalancing.

The problem is: When I try to add a third slave node, pgpool show the status 0 or 3 for this new host. And even waiting for too long, it doesn't change.

If I change one of the well working hosts to the third node, it's goes down and the host that was down, starts working. I don't know if there is a limit, but pgpool documentation say that the limit is up to 127 slaves (0 slaves is allowed too).

- Trying to add a third node :

[image]

- Changing hosts:

[image]